# How to search and filter multiple array data items in search bar in iOS swift 3.0 version

Tags: ios, iphone, search, swift3, tableview

I have three labels in custom tableview; first label I have displayed country array data, in second label I have displayed states array data and in final label I have displayed fruits array data.

1. In search bar if I search the country I need to filter the regarding country data .
2. In search bar if I search the state I need to filter the regarding state data.
3. In search bar if I search the fruit I need to filter the regarding fruit data.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
let data: [Person] = []
var dataToDisplay: [Person] = []

let searchText = "asd"

dataToDisplay = data.filter { (person: Person) -> Bool in

   return person.name!.contains(searchText) || person.lastName!.contains(searchText) || person.dateOfBirth!.contains(searchText)
}
```

where Person is:

```
struct Person {

    let name: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let dateOfBirth: String?
}
```